# ERROR in Could not resolve moment/ts3.1-typings/moment

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

After upgrade angular version getting ERROR in Could not resolve moment/ts3.1-typings/moment
node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker-material/ngx-daterangepicker-material.d.ts

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have fixed it to add  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true property in
tsconfig.app.json file and remove "angularCompilerOptions": {    "enableIvy": false}.